# Matlab while loop screenshot reload

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of my screen every second and then save it.
I want to use this to play a game, where there is a counter. I thought a while loop would keep refreshing the imshow(screenshot) however, it does not. Here is my code:

```
 i = 1;    
 while i > 0 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Screenshot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    imshow(screenshot)
    robo = java.awt.Robot;
    t = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    %# Set the capture area as the size for the screen
    rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());

    %# Get the capture
    image = robo.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

    %# Save it to file
    filehandle = java.io.File(sprintf('capture%d.jpg', 1));
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'jpg',filehandle);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Load screen
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   

    screenshot = imread('capture1.jpg'); % is using as a test        
    screenshot = imcrop(screenshot,[360 205 520 423]);                
 end
```

Comment: `screenshot` does not look like it is initialized before you start your `while` loop.  You are calling it before you are assigning it to anything.  What happens when you put it at the end, after you run `imcrop` on `screenshot`?  BTW, this will not take snapshots every second.  This will create screenshots as fast as it can cycle the `while` loop.  You should probably `pause` the loop for a second.  Put `pause(1);` at the end of the loop too so you can pause for 1 second before cycling to the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **drawnow** to update the current figure: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html?refresh=true